# Typing comments feels sluggish on CR compared to other SE sites.

Tags: bug, status-completed

For a while now typing comments on CR has felt very sluggish compared to comments on other sites such as SO and MSO.

Is there anything we can do to improve this?

I'm currently using Firefox 4.0.1 on windows XP in-case it matters.

Comment: No-repro on IE7/winXP, but that doesn't mean much.

Comment: @Michael K, I'm also using a computer getting close to 8 years old ... this might be exacerbating it.

Answer (score 2):

There *was* an issue where (in technical terms) we dropped a primary index which may explain some of the perceived sluggishness. But the problem was fixed so there should be no further performance problems related to that issue.

Comment: When I type a comment on MSO, there is little to no noticeable delay between typing something and seeing it show in the text box. Here, it's not uncommon for the text shown to fall 4-8 characters behind by the end of the line. The performance issue I think you might be be referring to was was on questions and answers where it would regularly fall 2-3 words behind. Typing questions and answers now seem to respond much faster than it did but there is still a noticeable delay when typing comments.

Comment: If the performance was the same across the SE network then I wouldn't worry about it. But since it performs better on SO & MSO I thought there might be some low hanging fruit here.